# how to get id_token in Python Flask OpenID?

Tags: python, flask, openid

I have successfully implemented Keycloak OpenID + Python (v3.6) Flask integration using [Flask-oidc](https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I use below code to get user info,access_token and refresh_token

```
oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)
info = oidc.user_getinfo(['preferred_username', 'email', 'sub', 'given_name', 'iss'])
access_token = oidc.get_access_token()
refresh_token = oidc.get_refresh_token()
```

And got the results as well. But for a reason i need **id_token** as well. I tried,

```
oidc.get_cookie_id_token()
```

(which is already deprecated), but it gave decoded result not encoded token.

Anybody know how to get **id_token** from flask-oidc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution,

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials
id_token_jwt = OAuth2Credentials.from_json(oidc.credentials_store[info.get('sub')]).id_token_jwt
```